# Sodium dithionite reduction of nitro group to amine

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, redox, aromatic-compounds

I've recently come across the synthesis of 3-aminopthalhydrazine from 3-nitropthalhydrazine where the reducing agent used was [sodium dithionite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_dithionite) ($\ce{Na2S2O4}$). I wanted to know what the mechanism of this reaction was but I'm unable find any mechanism online. Can anyone help me with that?

[image]